# ClickOnce application throws Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002

Tags: c#

I have a C# WinForm application which at some point is required to restart itself.

When it does, it throws the following error:

> *Invalid dll or dll not found! : MyLib.Dll The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)*

This error pops up after the App has closed and is trying to restart.

Also, this only happens when the App is installed on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7 installed.

The code which requests the restart of the application is:

```
ProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
Info.Arguments = "/C timeout /T 5 /NOBREAK && \"" + 
Application.ExecutablePath + "\""; 
Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
Info.CreateNoWindow = true; 
Info.FileName = "cmd.exe"; 
Process.Start(Info); 
Application.Exit(0);
```

The *MyLib.dll* exists and it is properly referenced.

After the error message, if I start the App manually, it works just fine.

Any clues on what this might be causing this error?

Comment: do you know there is a static `Application.Restart()` method?

Comment: Yes. Tried with Application.Restart() but when I do, it throws an error message saying App is already started. Only 1 instance of the app can run at a time. My thoughts is that it does not fully close.

Comment: so, I think the reason the same - your app not closed properly even after 5 second delay. Find why is this happening and all will be fine.

Comment: Did you set Info.WorkingDirectory?

Comment: As a debugging technique, use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to monitor which paths are used to locate the missing DLL.  You just need to set up some filters based on process name and file path.

Comment: @PepitoSh the app starts from the shell so we assume UseShellExecute to be true. In this case: "_When UseShellExecute is true, the working directory of the application that starts the executable is also the working directory of the executable._" - taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @mb14 so have you figured out where does the app look for the dll?

Comment: @kennyzx currently reading about ProcMon. I have partially managed to break the sollution and receive the same error on a Windows 7 machine and now have to check both Windows version's app error with ProcMon. Will post the result.

Comment: The ProcMon result shows the App is looking in C:\MyLib.dll and the result is NAME NOT FOUND. @kennyzx You should add your comment as an answer so I can validate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common technique to investigate "DLL Not Found" issues is to use [tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to monitor which locations are used to locate the missing DLL.

If the DLL does exist at the expected location, for example, in the same folder as the executable, then the problem might be caused by the fact that another folder is set as the working directory.